# R Highcharter - Navigator as input

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I am using the Highcharter library in my R Shiny apps to build some dashboards and I was wondering if it would be possible to use the navigator (hc_navigator) as an input.

For example: by adjusting the time window of the chart in my graph, I'd like to calculate the avg or the sum of the displayed data point in the chart. Of course, I'd like this to be dynamic (i.e. any time that I adjust the time window with the navigator, I want the calculated value to update)

**Example** - This is my baseline chart: [Baseline chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNYe1.png). I want to add a box which calculates the avg of the data points displayed in it. But, whenever I adjust the navigator (pls see here: [nav-adjusted chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCd8w.png)), I want the avg to change according to the data points which remain in the chart.

Does anybody have any idea on how to achieve something like this? Hope I was clear enough :)

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Comment: can you specify what you have tried? and add some fiddle.

Comment: @KrishnaKanth I added two screenshots of my charts and explained what I would like to achieve. Hope it helps!